# keywords list for app search on user's phone

Tags: java, android, search, indexing, google-play

When the user looks for an app on his phone, if he does not find directly the icon of my app, he will enter some keywords in the app search field in order to find it.

It seems that the search will match with the keywords entered in `<string name="app_name">`.

I enter in the field the name of my app (a trademark). I don't want to add keywords in the field (that would make easier the finding of my app if the user does not remember my app name) because the title below my app icon would be truncated.

So, where can I add keywords that are searchable by the user on its phone ? 
 By the way, is there a limit to the number of characters of "app_name" ?

Thanks !

Comment: On the device menu (12 character max). On the App Store (30 character max).

Comment: On Android, are the extra characters of "app_name" indexed ?

Comment: Have you found the way?

Answer (score 0):

This will vary from launcher to launcher, but most launchers only search on app name.